# How to draw a section of a circle using System.Windows.Shapes.Path?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, shapes

I have a Silverlight application where I draw lines on a picture by instantiating an instance of System.Windows.Shapes.Line and then adding it to MainCanvas.Children.

I would like to similarly add some circle segments.  If I understand correctly, I will want to use the Path class.

I have the following requirement.  I have (x,y) coordinates for the center of the circle.  I have the radius r.  I need to draw an arc that is a subset of the circle with center (x,y) and radius r.  I have two angles a1 and a2 between which I need to draw the arc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the [PathGeometry syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).

Consider something like:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Transparent">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry Figures="M 0,0 A 15,15 90 0 1 15,15" />
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

This will draw a 90-degree circular arc starting at `0,0`, ending at `15,15` in a clockwise direction.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to build a string that identifies the path using an arc, which is supported by WPF.
The string follows the syntax [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041%28VS.95%29.aspx).

However, the parameters must first be converted to the arc format given in the syntax,
since the values used are a little different:

First, convert the angles `a1` and `a2` to radians, if they aren't already.

```
a1=a1*Math.PI/180;
a2=a2*Math.PI/180;
```

Then, calculate the start and end point of the arc:

```
double startX = centerX+Math.Cos(a1)*r;
double startY = centerY+Math.Sin(a1)*r;
double endX = centerX+Math.Cos(a2)*r;
double endY = centerY+Math.Sin(a2)*r;
```

Then, calculate whether the difference between the angles is PI or greater, then whether a1 is less than a2.

```
bool largeArc = Math.Abs(a2-a1)>=Math.PI;
bool sweep = (a1<a2);
```

Finally, construct the path.

```
string path=String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
     "M {0},{1} A {2},{3} 0 {4} {5} {6},{7}",startX,startY,r,r,
     largeArc ? 1 : 0, sweep ? 1 : 0,endX,endY);
```

That's the path string, not the Path object, that you'll use in defining the path.